# org.jsoup.Jsoup not handling javascript links?

Tags: java, jsoup, xss

I'm trying to sanitize a text string containing possibly malicious content (XSS) using the Java lib Jsoup. I must allow <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a> links, but I don't want to allow javascript links for XSS reasons.

The test case below will fail since the javascript protocol is still allowed. Any ideas on how to solve this using Jsoup built in functions?

```
@Test
public void test() {

    Whitelist tWhitelist = Whitelist.none();

    tWhitelist.addAttributes("a", "href");
    tWhitelist.removeProtocols("a", "href", "javascript");      

    String tUnsafe = "<a href=\"javascript:alert(1)\">Link</a> is a link.";
    assertEquals("Link is a link.", Jsoup.clean(tUnsafe, tWhitelist));
}

    org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Link] is a link.> but was:<[<a href="javascript:alert(1)">Link</a>] is a link.>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused you are adding the `a` **tag** in the whitelist, you can use `none` whitelist directly, like:

```
Whitelist tWhitelist = Whitelist.none();

String tUnsafe = "<a href=\"javascript:alert(1)\">Link</a> is a link.";
assertEquals("Link is a link.", Jsoup.clean(tUnsafe, tWhitelist));
```

Or you can use `basic` white list to keep the other href, like:

```
    Whitelist tWhitelist = Whitelist.basic();

    tWhitelist.removeProtocols("a", "href", "javascript");
    String tUnsafe = "<a href=\"javascript:alert(1)\">Link</a> is a link.<a href=\"http://www.google.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">google</a>";
    assertEquals("<a rel=\"nofollow\">Link is a link.</a><a href=\"http://www.google.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">google</a>", Jsoup.clean(tUnsafe, tWhitelist));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out myself... This will make the specified protocols valid but the javascript protocol to be removed

```
    Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();

    whitelist
        .addTags("a")
        .addAttributes("a", "href")
        .addProtocols("a", "href", "http", "https", "mailto");

    String safeText = Jsoup.clean(untrustedText, whitelist);
```